# Why does docopt exits the script after parsing the parameters?

Tags: python, docopt

I use `docopt` for some time now and on a new script I cannot manage to pass through the argument parsing:

```
# coding=utf-8
"""
API server for the infoscreen frontends

Usage:
    python3 webserver.py [options]

Options:
    --bind ADDRESS  address to bind to  [default: 0.0.0.0]
    --galarmclock URL  URL for the galarmclock API [default: http://10.100.10.202:8082]
    --loglevel LOG  logging level   [default: logging.DEBUG]
    --console   log to console [default: False]
    --syslog    log to syslog [default: False]

"""

import docopt

# process arguments
args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
print(args)
```

All paramters (arguments) are optional and have a default so why does the script stops?

```
C:\Python3\python.exe C:/tst.py
Usage:
    python3 webserver.py [options]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the usage part:

```
Usage:
    python3 webserver.py [options]
```

Docopt expects the first string in the usage part to be your program, and not python. So docopt will interpret this as `python3` being your program, and that it always takes a command that is called `webserver.py`. If you remove the `python3` part it should work fine like this:

```
Usage:
    webserver.py [options]
```

From [docopt's documentation](http://docopt.org/) we have:

> Text occuring between keyword usage: (case-insensitive) and a visibly empty line is interpreted as list of usage patterns. The first word after usage: is interpreted as the program's name.